# Slim: Error using Wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

This is my first time using `Slim` and i wanted to give it a try using `WampServer` in an alias page, my plan is to make a `Restful API` for some application, everything works fine when the page loads everything but `Slim`, but when i get to a request which requires `Slim` to be loaded, i get `404 not found` error, i thought this was `.htaccess` problem so i made the file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /webpages/organizer 2.0/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

`Slim` file is in api folder so i added `RewriteBase` in order to make every request from api to be redirected to `index.php`, So when i try another request, i get `500 Internal Server Error`

i have no clue what makes this happen because i am using this same rules for another application with `Yii` framework and it works fine, even when i delete this `.htaccess` file and try again but this time requesting the specific file, i still get `404 not found` but with `Slim` template error

index.php

```
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/test/:word', function($word){
    echo $word;
});

$app->run();
```

folder structure:

```
organizer 2.0 {
    vendor: {
        autoload.php,
        Slim: {
            ...
        }
    },
    api: {
        .htaccess,
        index.php
    },
    bower_components: {
        ...
    },
    index.php
}
```

***note:*** Without `.htaccess` i have tried accessing `localhost/webpages/organizer 2.0/api/index.php/test/hello` and get 404 error from slim, but with `.htaccess` trying the request `localhost/webpages/organizer 2.0/api/test/hello` returns internal error

Answer (score 0):

after hours of changing code, unistalling and reinstalling, i have found that the problem was in `.htaccess`, looks like in `RewriteBase` has some problems with folders that has space in their name so i renamed the root folder to this
`webpages/organizer2.0/api`